# Is this a valid regular expression in IIS 7?

Tags: regex, iis

Further to my question at [How do write a rewrite rule in IIS that allows HTML anchors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893620/how-do-write-a-rewrite-rule-in-iis-that-allows-html-anchors) I was wondering if I can do the following or alternatively if there is a similar option to what is available in Apache e.g. [mod_rewrite with anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686075/mod-rewrite-with-anchor-link)

```
<match url="^ts\/tcs\.aspx$" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.abc.com" />
<conditions>
   <add input="{UrlEncode:{URL}}" pattern="#" />
</conditions>
```

Comment: IIS7 provides a nice, integrated means to test your regular expressions when you set them up in the `Edit Inbound Rule` page.

Comment: @Kirk Woll - I tried that but it doesn't allow me to test encoded values

Comment: Once again -- everything after the hash (including that symbol) will NOT be sent to a server (it is client-side ONLY), therefore you cannot match it in any way.

Comment: @LazyOne - Is that limited to just IIS or Apache as well?

Comment: @LazyOne - When you say `hash (including that symbol)` what is the difference between hash and the symbol?

Comment: Any web server -- the browser itself should not send it to a server in first place. Of course -- if you send such request manually via code and corresponding function/class/component does not strictly follow standards, then it may get sent and then you will have it as part of query string (but the web server _may_ reject such request).

Comment: If URL is: `/something.php?task=show#kitten`, then `#kitten` is the hash (including the actual hash symbol `#`). The proper name of `kitten` here is [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

Comment: @LazyOne - Happy to award your reply as an answer if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

Everything after the hash (including the hash symbol itself) will NOT be sent to a server (it is client-side ONLY), therefore you cannot match it in any way.

It is not IIS restriction -- any web server does (better say, should do) the same -- the browser itself should not send it to a server in first place. Of course -- if you send such request manually via custom code (PHP, ASP.NET etc) and corresponding function/class/component does not strictly follow standards, then it may get sent and then you will have it as part of query string (but the web server *may* reject such request, although unlikely).

If URL is: `/something.php?task=show#kitten`, then `#kitten` is the hash (including the actual hash symbol `#`). The proper name of `kitten` here is [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).