# Remove '#' in Url from IIS

Tags: angular, iis, deployment, iis-express

I have an angular application and deployed it in IIS.
The URL is as follows: **sample.contoso.com/#/**

I have removed hash location Strategy and now the URL is as follows: **sample.contoso.com**

But we have shared some links for analytics containing #.
Can we add a rewrite rule like this in IIS

URL : **sample.contoso.com/#/Home?id=1**

rewrite URL : **sample.contoso.com/?id=1**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Comment: No @yurongDai. There are some old links existing with #Home. We need to handle those as well. In our new solution we removed hash location strategy. I am looking for a way to handle them through redirect but not through code.

Comment: If you want to use redirects, you can create redirect rules using the IIS URL Rewrite module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module. If you encounter errors caused by rewriting or redirecting, you can use FRT to troubleshoot and debug URL rewriting rules. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules.

Answer (score 0):

The portion of the URL after # (fragment) is never sent to the server in the request for the page as per HTTP spec. If you open your web inspector and watch the request for the page, you will see that the #/Home portion is not included in the request at all. Therefore, URL rewrite won't see it.

Similar threads:

[How do write a rewrite rule in IIS that allows HTML anchors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893620/how-do-write-a-rewrite-rule-in-iis-that-allows-html-anchors)

[How does IIS URL Rewrite handle # anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422734/how-does-iis-url-rewrite-handle-anchor-tags)